# Excel VBA To Set Variable To Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I am trying to set a `Worksheet` variable to the `Activesheet` but I am getting an error of

> Object variable or with block variable not set

This is my syntax - what is the appropriate way of doing this?

```
Sub TestIt()
 Dim ws2 As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet

  ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
  ws1 = "Belgium"

  Debug.Print ws2
  Debug.Print ws1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- You need to use the `Set` keyword to assign object variables.

2- You cannot assign a sheet variable to a string directly, but you need to index through the `Worksheets` collection

3- You cannot `Debug.Print` a worksheet, but only its name or some cell inside

```
Sub TestIt()
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet

    Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Belgium")

    Debug.Print ws2.Name
    Debug.Print ws1.Cells(1,1).Value
End Sub
```